# Conditional constraint in pyomo

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to simulate battery charging using MILP with a similar approach used here (however I am using half an hour time periods rather than an hour) : https://github.com/gschivley/battery_model/blob/master/src/battery_model.py

However, I need to implement some conditional constraints. One of these is that if the battery charge state is above 80% or below 20% it must be returned to 50% within the next half hour.

In other words, I am trying to implement the logic below:

```
                    if model.S[t] <= 0.2:
                        model.S[t+1] ==  0.5
                    elif model.S[t] >= 0.8:
                        model.S[t+1] ==  0.5
                    else:
                        pass
```

I know this must be modelled using binary indicator variables but haven't been able to figure out how to implement this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a big-M constraint (or more accurately, a set of big-M constraints) for that.  Something similar to...

```
s[t] <= 0.8 + d[t] * M
s[t] >= 0.2 - d[t] * M

s[t+1] <= 0.5 + (1 - d[t]) * M
s[t+1] >= 0.5 - (1 - d[t]) * M
```

where `d[t]` is a binary indicator variable that indicates if the charge exceeded the soft bounds in period `t` and `M` is suitably large (`M` > max charge state)

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work for the most part. However, the constraint doesn't seem to hold when the value for charge is exactly 0.2 or 0.8. Is there any way to enforce this?

Comment: To your question:  Not really.  Constraints cannot employ strict inequalities for mathematical reasons.  You could always change the values to something like 0.201 and 0.799 if that works for what you intend.  Just don't go too crazy on the decimal places or you will run into numerical stability issues.